# Bad smell from varnish

Tags: wood, varnish, toxicity

I had my wooden floors refinished and the contractor did three coats of oil based varnish. It's been 6 months and there is still a strong smell. How do I get it to go away? It's giving me a headache and making me nauseous.

Thanks in advance for replying. I have tried snake plants, bowls of vinegar, running air purifiers, getting bags of activated charcoal put around the room, leaving windows open during the day. I heard sliced onions can help. I will probably try it!

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Sorry for your trouble, but this isn't something that has an easy *do this* kind of solution. Generally oil-based varnishes do of course have a significant smell associated with them (some more than others), and this can take a while to dissipate. But *six months*??? I presume you've read about the things to try, even if you didn't already try some things yourself already because they're obvious/you'd do them anyway, like leaving the windows open for extended periods? Getting air in (provides oxygen for curing), and then having it leave, is key to the solution....

Comment: This issue of a lingering odour in an enclosed space is one reason that there is very widespread advice not to finish the insides of drawers, chests, cabinets and cupboards with oil-based finishes, or linseed oil. In a fully enclosed space the smell can linger and linger for an extraordinarily long time. Sort of like you'd hope/expect the smell from a cedar lining to still be noticeable; although obviously one is desirable and the other not, the timeframes could be similar......

Comment: To save everyone some time and effort, please [edit] your question to indicate the things you've done so far to try to eliminate the odors. It doesn't make sense for us to tell you to do something that you've already tried (unless, of course, the suggestion is "keep doing it").

Comment: Well I think you can firmly put bowls of vinegar and sliced onions into the pile titled "Ridiculous Suggestions From the Internet"..... and then forget about them forever! Probably plants too. Air purifiers seem like they'd work, but I believe from some scathing reviews of the sector I've watched online they primarily work (IF at all!) on particulates, so could essentially have zero effect. Air flow is the key, or to put it another way *air exchange*.